# Camel: "file" component, but only pass file name as body

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to process potentially large files using Camel, and am worried about them "fitting" in the body of a Camel `Message`.  Is there a way I can just pass the name (path) of the file as the body of the message, and then in a processor use that to read from disk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just pass in a java.io.File instance. This is essentially what the Camel file component does itself (although its placed inside a WrappedFile, due sharing code with the ftp components).

You can of course also just store the name of the file as  a String, and then from the processor access the file, either by

```
String name = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
File file = new File(name);
...
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
// read the file from the stream, etc.
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly.  Camel does **not** load the file's contents into the message when it consumes it, but rather passes a `File` (wrapped inside a `WrappedFile`) object?  And when I ask for the body as a `byte[]` (`exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class)`), _then_ it loads the body?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The content of the file is loaded on demand.