# Cache Streaming Treat large file

Tags: java, xml, caching, apache-camel

I’m working on a subject “Using Cache with Apache Camel and How to treat large file”.

The purpose is to treat large file with camel without loading the file into memory because it’s a huge file over 5 GO.

We found several tracks, the first track is to use the splitter component, to allow us to read the file for example line by line or block by block, however if we use the splitter we are not able to read again the file from the beginning, a functional need is to be able to read some part of the file even when the split is finished.

So we have to use a cache system, to put blocks in the cache to reuse them.

So we thought that is was compulsory to use the class CachedOutputStream to write on disk some part of the file after the splitter , this class also provides the ability to encrypt data on disk.

Example below :

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="false" streamCache="true">

    <streamCaching id="myCacheConfig"  spoolDirectory="target/cachedir" spoolThreshold="16"/>

    <route id="SPLIT-FLOW" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="file:src/data/forSplitCaching\SimpleRecord?noop=true"/>
        <split streaming="true">
            <tokenize token="\n"/>
            <to uri="direct:PROCESS-BUSINESS"/>
        </split>
    </route>

    <route id="PROCESS-BUSINESS" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="direct:PROCESS-BUSINESS"/>
        <bean ref="ProcessBusiness" method="dealRecord"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${in.header.CamelSplitComplete} == "true"</simple>
                <to uri="direct:STREAM-CACHING"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>

    <route id="STREAM-CACHING">
        <from uri="direct:STREAM-CACHING"/>
        <bean ref="ProcessStreamCaching" method="usingStream"/>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
            <simple>${header.CamelFileName}.${header.CamelSplitIndex}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="file:src/out"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

The method dealRecord  puts each line splitted into a cache:

```
public void dealRecord(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 

   String body; 
   File file; 
   String[] files; 
   boolean isSplitComplete; 

   body = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody(); 
   isSplitComplete = (boolean) exchange.getProperties().get("CamelSplitComplete"); 

   CachedOutputStream cos = new CachedOutputStream(exchange, false); 
   cos.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8")); 

   file = new File("target/cachedir"); 
   files = file.list(); 
   for (String nameTmpfile : files) { 
      LOG.info("Genered File [" + nameTmpfile + "]"); 
   } 

   lstCache.add(cos); 

   if(isSplitComplete){ 
      exchange.getIn().setHeader("Cached",lstCache); 
   } 
}
```

The method usingStream,can use each cache existing in the header

```
public byte[] usingStream(Exchange exchange) throws InputStreamException { 

   final ArrayList<CachedOutputStream> lstcache; 
   byte[] bytesMessage; 
   StringBuilder messageCompleteOut = new StringBuilder(); 
   InputStream is = null; 

   lstcache = (ArrayList<CachedOutputStream>) exchange.getIn().getHeader("Cached"); 
   for (CachedOutputStream oneCache : lstcache) { 
      try { 
         is = oneCache.getWrappedInputStream(); 
         String messageInputstream = toString(is); 
         LOG.info("Message of Cache ["+ messageInputstream +"]"); 
         messageCompleteOut.append(messageInputstream); 
         messageCompleteOut.append(System.lineSeparator()); 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         LOG.error(InputStreamException.ERROR_MANIPULATING_INPUT_STREAM_CHANNEL); 
         throw new InputStreamException(InputStreamException.ERROR_MANIPULATING_INPUT_STREAM_CHANNEL,e); 
      } 
      // On ferme le flux 
      IOHelper.close(is); 
   } 
   bytesMessage = messageCompleteOut.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
   return bytesMessage; 
}
```

Is that solution seems ok  ? or maybe there is a better way ?

thxs

Answer (score 0):

GenericFileMessage (message implementation used by file component) does not load the file content into memory unles needed. So in fact you only need to make sure you do not access the body in way forcing it to convert it. You can also write your own message (inheriting from GenericFileMessage) and prevent such conversion, or return something different (some kind of "digest").

The processors along the way can get location of the file in filesystem (from message headers) and open it directly, possibly replacing the file message with some other message.

Comment: This class GenericFileMessage allows you to manage messages, by default, the file is loaded into memory, any methods available to  specify the establishment in a specific cache.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9389465/2956532

The content of file is not loaded into memory. Camel in fact passes WrappedFile instance in the message body.